# ¿Como configurar entornos de desarrollo en android e iOS?

Tags: android, ios

Tengo 4 entornos en los que debe de probar los desarrolladores

1. Desarrollo
2. Pruebas
3. Producción Dummy
4. Producción

Necesito que los desarrolladores puedan realizar pruebas en los diferentes entornos y cada entorno es igual a un dominio y servidor diferente
¿como podrían estar cambiando de entorno si correr el riesgo de que el dominio de desarrollo se publique en las tiendas de android e iOS?
Si quisiera presentar la aplicación a clientes ¿como podría descargar la aplicación de la tienda y afectar al servidor Dummy en vez del productivo?

Comment: En iOS tienes la opción de usar TestFlight para probar las aplicaciones sin que se publiquen en el market. Sin embargo, desconozco si hay algo similar en Android.

Answer (score 2):

En **iOS** para testing puedes usar **[Testflight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)**. En cuanto a **Android** hay una opción para publicar tu app de testeo, existen 3 diferentes formas: **APK de Producción**, **Beta testing** y **Alpha testing**.

En las cuales tu decides en que momento sales del testeo para poder publicar una *apk* de producción, te pongo un *screenshot*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto me refería a las 3 fases, el círculo de color verde es la parte donde colocas tus APK para producción, el cual ya ha sido probada por los usuarios y con los cambios que le hayas agregado personalmente o el conjunto de cambios agregados sugeridos por tus usuarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se recomienda comenzar con un pequeño grupo de verificadores Alfa y, después, expandir tu prueba a un grupo de prueba Beta más grande.

**Prueba Beta cerrada:** Considera usar pruebas Beta cerradas para un grupo más reducido, como dentro de tu empresa o equipo, o cuando ya determinaste los usuarios exactos que deseas que prueben tu app. Si quieres probar una app que ya publicaste anteriormente, solo los usuarios dentro del grupo de prueba recibirán una actualización para la versión Alfa o Beta.

**Prueba Beta abierta:** Considera usar pruebas Beta abiertas para un grupo más amplio y publicar la versión Beta de tu app en Play Store. Si realizas una prueba Beta abierta, cualquier usuario podrá unirse al programa Beta y enviarte comentarios privados. Antes de elegir esta opción, asegúrate de que tu app esté lista para su publicación en Play Store.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]